# Certificate error when pushing nuget symbol package

Tags: debugging, package, nuget, push, symbols

I am trying to push a symbol package to the nuget symbol server. The API key has been set and the regular package has uploaded just fine. However, when I try to push the symbol package it fails saying the following:

```
PM> nuget push .\Tanneryd.BulkInsert.1.0.1-alfa.symbols.nupkg -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net/ Pushing Tanneryd.BulkInsert.1.0.1-alfa.symbols.nupkg to the symbol server (https://nuget.smbsrc.net/)...   PUT https://nuget.smbsrc.net/api/v2/package/   PUT https://nuget.smbsrc.net/api/v2/package/   PUT https://nuget.smbsrc.net/api/v2/package/ nuget : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. At line:1 char:1
+ nuget push .\Tanneryd.BulkInsert.1.0.1-alfa.symbols.nupkg -source htt ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The underlying ...secure channel.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Comment: The domain has now a valid certificate again, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that https://nuget.smbsrc.net/ currently has a certificate error (e.g. expired certificate).  When I go here from IE I see:

```
This site is not secure

This might mean that someone’s trying to fool you or steal any info you send to the server. You should close this site immediately.
```

**Update**

I was able to publish by specifying HTTP rather than secure.  Example:

```
nuget push dist/MyPackage.1.0.0.symbols.nupkg -Source http://nuget.smbsrc.net  -ApiKey [my key]
```

Comment: The trouble is also reported as an NuGet [issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6082).